# How to restart samba server?

Tags: samba

Sorry this is a little embarassing but I'm trying to set up my own server for the first time.  I found great tutorial online.

http://www.intac.net/build-your-own-server/

I'm stuck at the 2nd to last line of step 4.  Apparently there is no samba directory in init.d.

Why isn't there a samba directory in init.d?

Would the following work?

```
# sudo restart smbd
# sudo restart nmdb
```

Comment: If your `#` means you are logged in as superuser, then you don't need to run the commands with `sudo`, else the commands you mentioned are fine.

Comment: If you're embarrassed as a first timer, what does that make me when I've had a server running for years and needed this question :)

Comment: perhaps service samba-ad-dc restart?

Comment: `samba-ad-dc.service` is the Samba Active Directory / Domain Controller service, which is not enabled by default. So this unfortunately is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Start

```
sudo service smbd start
```

Stop

```
sudo service smbd stop
```

Restart

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Why not use the Upstart syntax like mentioned by the user?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. I'm just lazy and `sudo <start|stop|status|restart|reload> <job>` is just shorter. ;)

Comment: @htorque I cant really remember why I made the recommendation like this also, maybe I seen something that ticked me off and I recommended this way, or its just my brain thinking about services all the time. Thx for the input! ;)

Comment: FYI, I had to use `samba` instead of `smbd` in my command line.

Comment: I am using Kali linux and I too, had to use samba instead of smbd

Comment: I also had to use `samba` instead of `smbd` in my command line. My restart command, therefore, was `sudo service samba restart`. This was for a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Does not work:
smbd: unrecognized service

For others the service name is samba, this answer is not complete.

Answer (score 20):

Starting with 15.04 and systemd, the command is `systemctl restart smbd`

Comment: the service is smbd, not smdb

Comment: +1 for updating an old question. But [Ubuntu 15.04 was first version to use systemd](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2895517/ubuntu-just-switched-to-systemd-the-project-sparking-controversy-throughout-linux.html).

Comment: Duh. Info online is so.. contradicting. I guess like it might be because back then it [hadn't be](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1427654) a totally full 100% switch.

Comment: Is there any significant difference compared to "sudo service smbd xxx"?

Comment: Yes, a total one? Service is a command for System V systems afaik.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this way:

**Start**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd start
```

**Stop**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd stop
```

**Restart**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

---

If you got an error, try using these commends this *nmbd* instead.

Comment: Is there any significant difference compared to "sudo service smbd xxx"?

Answer (score 11):

you may also try this :

check the name of the service:

```
service --status-all
```

restart the service

```
sudo service samba restart
```

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL you start smb and nmb:

```
systemctl start smb
systemctl start nmb
```

Next, check if they started:

```
ps -elf | grep smbd
ps -elf | grep nmbd
```