# My Samba server isn't showing up in windows

Tags: server, samba

I have just made a Ubuntu server (16.04.1 LTS) and I have followed all the tourials on how to make one and it is not showing up in Windows!!!
The only settings I have changes in smb.conf is

```
Workgroup = SANCTUARY
```

*Sanctuary is my workgroup*

---

And in Share definitions I made this

```
[Nic]
Comment = Nic
Path = /server/Nic
Browsable = yes
Read only = no
Guest ok = no
```

Then I restarted

Thank you and if you have have an answer I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The google ranking of this answer is high, so I thought I'd contribute the current Windows 10 solution.
**Windows 10 no longer supports NetBIOS discovery.**

You can fix this by enabling the insecure SMBv1 (or so I've read), but that's a bad idea and you have to do it on all your clients. The best way is to implement *Web Service Discovery* on your Linux server.

[wsdd](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd) accomplishes this. Pre-made service files are available from the guy's git also (although for Ubuntu I had to change the group from nobody to nogroup to get it to work). It works great.

Comment: On a related note, the nmb service is no longer needed. Run only smb and wsdd.

Comment: The fact that Samba met packages don't depend on WSDd is a moral crime.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to share files between a Linux Mint 18 Samba server and a Windows 10 workstation.  Through some digging I found this process:

### Linux Samba Server

Check your /etc/samba/smb.conf for syntax errors by running:

> testparm

Ideally we are looking for this on stdout there somewhere:

> Loaded services file OK.

If you are using system-config-samba, let's squash a bug:

> sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
>
> sudo chmod 644 /etc/libuser.conf

Now restart the samba server any number of ways depending on your distro. Here's a few examples of that:  [How to restart samba server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79078/how-to-restart-samba-server)

> sudo service smbd restart
>
> sudo service nmbd restart

Now that's done, we can check to be sure the smbd and nmbd processes are running with this:

> ps aux | grep mbd

You should get something like this:

> root     18379  0.0  0.2 337912 15856 ?        Ss   03:04   0:00 smbd -D -s /etc/samba/smb.conf
>
> root     18386  0.0  0.0 240452  5988 ?        Ss   03:04   0:00 nmbd -D -s /etc/samba/smb.conf

If they aren't running, fire them up.  Check your syslog for errors.

### Windows client machine

(where the smb server isn't showing up in the network).

Now the fun part.  Open a file explorer window and in the address bar type the name of your samba server and append a '**.local**' to it such as this:

> \\mysambaserver.local

If you have configured samba correctly, it'll pop right up.  Afterward, you could right click this server in explorer and create a shortcut in the start menu or your quick access list.

### TL;DR

I give credit where it's due:  [Credit](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1329562#p1329562) goes to altair4 on the Linux Mint forums (a beast). If you have more questions about this method, do yourself a solid... [check his post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1329562#p1329562) to see if you missed anything during setup or configuration.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply - I tried this and no luck but I reinstalled on another computer and it worked.

Comment: omg yes! this worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: Did you restart the smbd service?

The best way to diagnose is to try listing the shares,

```
smbclient -L yourhostname
```

And then accessing from your local computer:

```
smbclient //yourhostname/Nic
```

Source: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html

If success, then check your firewall for remote access: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-samba-to-communicate-with-other-windowslinux-systems/

Comment: Yes I did restart... Sorry for not telling you. (My host name is ubuntu.     With your last line of code, I made a directory called /server/Nic. So would I have to write 'smbclient /ubuntu/server/Nic'.             Thanks for replying

Comment: **In reply with your second fix (smbclient -L ubuntu) it come up with 'WARNING "syslog" option is deprecated' - the same thing came up when i ran 'testparm' ---- Then I put in the password then it came up with see link - [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-_fOoX3f0J-LWdrUzdLS25CU0E)

Comment: And with your third one it didn't work thanks

Comment: Your local path (/server/nic) has no bearing on smb/remote users. They just need your computername (ubuntu?) and the share name (nic).

Comment: //ubuntu/nic. Try IP instead of hostname too. //192.168.1.whatever/nic